# Group by of list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list with 5 elements

```
data = List((List(c1),Y), (List(c1),N), (List(c1),N), (List(c1),Y), (List(c1),Y))
```

And I want to create a list following:

```
List((List(c1),Y,0.666), (List(c1),N),0.333)
```

Any tips on the best way to do this?

I am using scala if that's any help

Comment: Are you using Scala-Spark DataFrame, Dataset/RDD or plain Scala?

Comment: Is this question about Spark or Scala? You dont need Spark for a list of 5 elements for sure!

Comment: Why the inner lists always have one element? What should happen if they have multiple elements? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @ Luis: That is just the simplest example. I need a solution for 1 list with many elements as follows:  List((List(c1, a1),Y), (List(a1),Y), (List(c1, a1),N), (List(a1),N), (List(a1),Y)). and I want to the result as: List((List(c1, a1),Y, 0.5), (List(c1, a1),N, 0.5), (List(a1),Y, 0.66), (List(a1),N, 0.33))

Answer (score 0):

```
object Grouping {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data = List((List("c1"),"Y"), (List("c1"),"N"), (List("c1"),"N"), (List("c1"),"Y"), (List("c1"),"Y"))

    val result = data.groupBy(grp => (grp._1,grp._2))
      .mapValues(count =>  BigDecimal(count.size.toDouble).setScale(3)./(BigDecimal(data.size.toDouble).setScale(3))
        .setScale(3, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
        .map( k => (k._1._1,k._1._2,k._2)).toList
    println("result=="+result)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def calculatePercentages(data : List[(List[String], String)]): List[((List[String], String),BigDecimal)] = {
    val (yesRows, noRows) = data.partition(_._2 == "Y")
    List((yesRows(0), (BigDecimal(yesRows.length) / BigDecimal(data.length)).setScale(3, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)),
      (noRows(0), (BigDecimal(noRows.length) / BigDecimal(data.length)).setScale(3, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)))
  }

scala> calculatePercentages(data)
res30: List[((List[String], String), BigDecimal)] = List(((List(c1),Y),0.600), ((List(c1),N),0.400))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your support. Your code ran properly on my first request. However, with more complex data as with a list below it is not as I expected.

```
    List(
(List(c1, a1),Y),
(List(a1),Y), 
(List(c1, a1),N),
(List(a1),N),
(List(a1),Y))
```

and i want the result is

```
List(
(List(c1, a1),Y, 0.5),
(List(c1, a1),N, 0.5),
(List(a1),Y, 0.66), 
(List(a1),N, 0.33),
)
```

I look forward to your support